# Controlling a slideshow with an external button

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

I'm using the pickachoose jQuery-Slider on my brothers page and he wants the slideshow to stop, when someone clicks on stories to see the other gallery-categories. (http://clients.desiign.de/goltz/archives/135) Is it possible to stop the slideshow from the stories-button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yup

```
<a href="javascript:$('.pika-imgnav a:first').click()">Stories</a>
```

Comment: This one works but when the slideshow has already been paused, this code restarts it again! Any ideas?

Comment: @JuliusKoroll I'd have to see the code again, but yes, this is supposed to work just like the pause button.  It can be modified though to accommodate that behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(".stories a").click(function(){
  $(".pika-stage img").stop();
});
```

Comment: I changed my slider to galleria and tried to work with the code. Sadly it doesnt seem to be so easy. I saw it works with pause but which element should be paused?