# Prevent multiple clicks on external controls while slider animation executes

Tags: jquery-plugins, jquery

I have a slider (using Liquid Slider) which I've hacked a bit to (i) create some colour transitions and (ii) use external prev/next arrows which both operate outside of the slider's plugin code.

I've got the transitions and arrows working to operate the slider but I can't prevent multiple clicks from running the colour transitions even when the slider is still moving between slides.

I've tried using `return false` and `e.stopImmediatePropagation()` to no avail.

Here's my code for the prev/next arrows:

```
$('.arrows a')
        .click(function(e) {
            var link = $(this);
            oldTab = $('.liquid-nav a.active'), newTab;
            oldTab.removeClass('active').prev().animate({opacity: 0}, 1000);
            if (link.hasClass('next')) {
                if (oldTab.parent().next().length) { // Test for looping slides
                    newTab = oldTab.parent().next().find('a');
                    newTabNum = theSlider.currentTab + 1;
                } else {
                    newTab = $('.tab1').find('a');
                    newTabNum = 0;
                }
                console.log( newTabNum );
                theSlider.setCurrent( newTabNum );
            } else {
                if (oldTab.parent().prev().length) { // Test for looping slides
                    newTab = oldTab.parent().prev().find('a');
                    newTabNum = theSlider.currentTab - 1;
                } else {
                    newTab = $('.tab' + theSlider.panelCount).find('a');
                    newTabNum = theSlider.panelCount - 1;
                }
                console.log( newTabNum );
                theSlider.setCurrent( newTabNum );
            }

            newTab.addClass('active').prev().animate({opacity: 1}, 1000);
            $('.liquid-nav').animate({borderTopColor: newTab.attr('data-colour')}, 1000);
            $('.arrows a').animate({backgroundColor: newTab.attr('data-colour')}, 1000);
        });
```

The slider plugin allows a callforward and callback, and I attempted to set a var `sliding` while the animation is happening in order to prevent the arrows from doing anything while the var is true, but unfortunately the timing wasn't right -- the callforward which set `sliding` to true didn't do it before the click handler was executed.

The code for the arrows is simple enough:

```
<div class="arrows">
    <a href="javascript:;" class="prev"></a>
    <a href="javascript:;" class="next"></a>
</div>
```

There are already several questions which relate to similar problems, but as mentioned I've tried the solutions suggested without much luck. Any help would be much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed it in the end by firing the `click` event used by the tabs, instead of repeating the code for the prev/next arrows' events (I got that idea from here [Controlling a slideshow with an external button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6833439/controlling-a-slideshow-with-an-external-button)). I also reimplemented the `sliding` var and it seems to work:

```
$('.arrows a').click(function() {
        if (!sliding) {
            //console.log(sliding);
            if ($(this).hasClass('next')) {
                newTab = (theSlider.currentTab === (theSlider.panelCount-1)) ? newTab = 1 : theSlider.currentTab + 2;
            } else {
                newTab = (theSlider.currentTab === 0) ? (theSlider.panelCount) : theSlider.currentTab;
            }
            //console.log(newTab);


            $('.liquid-nav .tab'+newTab+' a').click();
        }
    });
```

The tab code looks like this:

```
$('.liquid-nav a').each(function(i) {
        $(this)
            .click(function() {
                if (!$(this).hasClass('active') && !sliding) {
                    $('.liquid-nav a.active').removeClass('active').prev().animate({opacity: 0}, 1000);
                    $(this).addClass('active').prev().animate({opacity: 1}, 1000);
                    $('.liquid-nav').animate({borderTopColor: $(this).attr('data-colour')}, 1000);
                    sliding = true;
                    $('.arrows a').animate({backgroundColor: $(this).attr('data-colour')}, 1000, function() {
                        sliding = false;
                    });
                }
            })
            .prev().css('backgroundColor', $(this).attr('data-colour'));
    });
```

Changing `sliding` in the callback of the custom animation (which has the same duration as the slider plugin's animation) means I can control when the arrows and other tabs are able to execute the transitions.

Answer (score 0):

Test that maybe: {without seeing relevant HTML code }

```
$('.arrows a')
    .click(function (e) {
    //use selector relative to your slider, by default class liquid-slide
    if ($('.liquid-slider').is(':animated')) return;
    var link = $(this);
    //... all other code here
});
```